# SSH from Mac to Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, macos

I successfully ssh-ed to my Ubuntu machine from a PC through both local and over the internet. However, I got no luck with my Mac. I followed all the steps for SSH key gen and configuration and tried to ssh through both local and over the internet but no matter what I try I keep getting the same error message 
**Permission denied. (publickey)**

```
MacBook-Pro:~ mbp$ ssh -vT xxx@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
OpenSSH_5.9p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/mbp/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/mbp/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/mbp/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/mbp/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-3ubuntu1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-3ubuntu1 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
The authenticity of host 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/mbp/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/mbp/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: Try to connect again with `ssh -vvvT` to get some extra debugging information. I assume the key you are trying to use is in authorized_keys on the server correctly? What does the ssh/secure/etc. log on the server say about this attempt?

Comment: are you sure that you added the mac's *public key* to the `~xxx/.ssh/authorized_keys` file on the server?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your key is authorized on the server in `~xxx/.ssh/authorized_keys`, and make sure you've typed the server address correctly.

Chances are it will be one of those two things.

Answer (score 0):

You already have an entry in your ~/.ssh/known_hosts for the ip address you are attempting to ssh into, but the key is different.

You need to manually edit ~/.ssh/known_hosts and remove the line that contains the ip address of the server

**Bonus**

Run the following to remove the offending key automatically
(changing the ip address to the ip of the ubuntu server of course)

```
ssh-keygen -R 192.168.1.10
```